# EmEditor js macro: is it possible to use node.js API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macros, emeditor

Is it possible to use node.js API in EmEditor js macro? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; EmEditor's JS engine is JScript 5.8.